# How to fix 2 scollbars while using 2 fixed_columns in dataTables Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I'm using fixedColumns functionality present in the dataTables library to fix the leftmost column of my table. But using it results in 2 different independently scrollable scroll bars. I'd be grateful if anyone can tell me how to fix it? Here's my code for drawing tables.

```
function draw_table_fixed(table_id){
            TABLE=$('#'+table_id).DataTable({
            scrollY:false,
            scrollX:true, 
            paging: true, 
            fixedColumns:   {
                leftColumns: 1,
            },
            columnDefs: [
                {targets: 0, orderable: true},
                {targets: '_all', orderable: false}
            ]}) ;
        }
```

And here's what it looks like.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckD5W.png)

Comment: Your issue is [not reproducible for me](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html), based on the information in the question. The screenshot looks as if you may be using some additional styling framework. Perhaps that is interfering with the fixed columns extension.

Comment: Yes I'm using overlflow:auto ; for the tbody type, and using it results in the above situation

Comment: When you use the [Fixed Columns](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/) extension, DataTables actually draws multiple tables: "_the fixed columns are actually separate tables from the original DataTable (i.e. they are separate table elements)_". So, if you apply styling to a generic `tbody` you are affecting each separate table, independently. Bear that in mind when applying features such as `overflow:auto` to your page. Perhaps it would be simpler just to not use `overflow:auto` in this specific case.